# Trying to fill a form with a predefined xml file(cant change the xml file)

Tags: javascript, html, xml

What happeneds is that fills all fields with the first "value" it encounters on the xml file. In this case fills all fields with the date.

The xml file is inserted by the user with a html button

Function to fill the form, i know that the loop is always fetching the first "value" it encounters, but how do i fix it, without changing the xml file. I tried this, but doesn't work.

```
function populateData(form, xmlDoc){ 
"use strict";
var root = xmlDoc.documentElement;

for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
  var input = form.elements[i];
      if(input.name){ 
      var xmlElement = root.querySelector(input.name);     

    if(xmlElement[i].textContent !== xmlElement[i-1].textContent){
        input.value = xmlElement.textContent;
    }
      }
  }

}
```

Part of the XML FILE( i want to fill the form with the information between "value")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AssetInfo>
<customMetaData>
  <key>Data</key>
  <value>2018-05-23</value>
</customMetaData>
<customMetaData>
  <key>Hora</key>
  <value>11:00</value>
</customMetaData>
<customMetaData>
  <key>Sala</key>
  <value>1</value>
</customMetaData>
<customMetaData>
  <key>Edifício</key>
  <value>casa</value>
</customMetaData>
```

Part of the html form

```
    <input class="a" type="date" name="value" id="Data" placeholder="Data" />
    <input class="a" type="time" name="value" id="Hora" placeholder="Hora" />
    <input class="a" type="text" name="value" id="Sala" placeholder="Sala" />
    <input class="a" type="text" name="value" id="Edifício" placeholder="Edifício" />
    <input class="a" type="text" name="value" id="Cidade" placeholder="Cidade" />
    <input class="a" type="text" name="value" id="País" placeholder="País" />
```

Comment: Could you read the XML and iterate over the <customMetaData> nodes and store the values from the key and value child nodes in a map? Then you could iterate over the form, get the name, then just pull the value out of the map based on that key.

Comment: Do you have any example on how to do that, is my first try with xml files. But what are you saying is that comparing the key name i could get the correspondent value and write it on the form?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loadData(fileInput) {
  "use strict";
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', fileURL);
req.onload = function() {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromObject(fileURL, 'text/xml');
  populateData(fileInput.form, xmlDoc);
};

req.onerror = function() {
 URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
 console.log('Error loading XML file.');
};

 req.send();
}
```

HTML Button

```
<label><input class="button" style="display: none;" type="file"</label> 
onchange="loadData(this);">Ler XML
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the xml into a map and then use that map to find the value for the key that matches the input name

```js
// get an xmlDoc to work with for this snippet
var xmlString = `<AssetInfo>
<customMetaData>
  <key>Data</key>
  <value>2018-05-23</value>
</customMetaData>
<customMetaData>
  <key>Hora</key>
  <value>11:00</value>
</customMetaData>
<customMetaData>
  <key>Sala</key>
  <value>1</value>
</customMetaData>
<customMetaData>
  <key>Edifício</key>
  <value>casa</value>
</customMetaData></AssetInfo>`;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');

function populateData(form, xmlDoc){ 
"use strict";
var root = xmlDoc.documentElement;
// get all the customMetaData nodes
var metadataNodes = root.querySelectorAll('customMetaData');
// create an object to store the key/values
var map = {};
// iterate over the nodes and get the key and value to add to the map
  metadataNodes.forEach(function(metadata) {
    var key = metadata.querySelector('key').textContent;
    var value = metadata.querySelector('value').textContent;
    map[key] = value;
  });
  // interate over your form and find the value in the map for that input's name
  for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    var input = form.elements[i];
    if(input.name){ 
        input.value = map[input.name] || '';     
    }
    
  }
}

populateData(document.getElementById('myForm'), xmlDoc);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="Data" /><br />
    <input name="Hora" /><br />
      <input name="Sala" /><br />
        <input name="Edifício" /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Just one more question if u dont mind, Im using a html button where the user insert the xml file and im trying to adapt your code to mine but i dont know how, below is one of things i tried to do, if could take a look i would apreciated. Btw thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to read the xml file that the usrs selects, check out the JavaScript File Api's FileReader.